# Ansible for loop in task

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following example ansible task section that works fine:

```
- fortios_webfilter_profile:
    state: "present"
    webfilter_profile:
      name: "default"
      ftgd_wf:
        filters:
          -
            id: 1
            action: block
          -
            id: 2
            action: block
```

and I'd like to convert it to something like:

```
filters: |
  {% for category_id, category_action in category_info.items() %}
    -
      id: {{ category_id }}
      action: {{ category_action }}
  {% endfor %}
```

And the variable I'd want to loop is defined as:

```
category_info:
  1: block
  2: block
```

Which does not seem to work, the error I get is:

```
"msg": "dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value"
```

Comment: Since there might be dependencies based on the Ansible modules used, can you provide the full task or playbook?

Comment: Edited the question with the full task, it's the only task in a role, the variable is defined in the role's defaults/main.yml

Comment: What if you try surrounding your `{% for %}` loop with `{% filter from_yaml %}...{% endfilter %}`?

Comment: Using from_yaml works, thank you!

But also ansible-lint reports the error: "Value '{% filter from_yaml %}...{% endfilter %}' in the sub parameter field 'filters' must by a list, not 'str' ansible-lint(args[module])."

Is there maybe an other way to do it so ansible-lint does not complain?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a much simpler expression which will not trigger any linter warnings (according to your latest comment):

```yaml
- fortios_webfilter_profile:
    state: "present"
    webfilter_profile:
      name: "default"
      ftgd_wf:
        filters: "{{ category_info | dict2items(key_name='id', value_name='action') }}"
```

See the [`dict2items` filter documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html)

Comment: Thank you! I did not use this aproach because in fact there are other options beside 'id' and 'action' which might be added in the future, which might complicate things, using a for loop seemd to be the most flexible way.